# Inconsistent accessibility less accessible

Tags: c#

I've searched for answers on similar errors, but haven't been able to find any. Also I know how to fix the error (make all public - which I don't really want to do), but I don't really understand why this is not allowed. 
Anyway - I'm getting

> Inconsistent accessibility: property type
>   'E7XLibrary.Base.MultiSegmentBase' is less accessible than property
>   'E7XLibrary.E7XGroupBase.GroupSegment'

My MultiSegmentBase class is declared as an internal class (and so is the SegmentBase class):

```
internal class MultiSegmentBase : SegmentBase
```

I’m using a MultiSegmentBase instance as a protected abstract property in my public E7XGroupBase class:

```
public abstract class E7XGroupBase
{
    internal abstract UInt64 Length { get; }
    protected abstract MultiSegmentBase GroupSegment { get; }

    internal virtual void Wrap(BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        GroupSegment.Length = this.Length;
        GroupSegment.Wrap(writer);
    }
}
```

And lastly I have a devided public class E7XSessionGroup class that implements the abstract E7XGroupBase, like this

```
public class E7XSessionGroup : E7XGroupBase
{
    #region Properties
    private SessionGroupSegment _groupSegment = null;
    protected override MultiSegmentBase GroupSegment
    {
        get
        {
            if (_groupSegment == null)
                _groupSegment = new SessionGroupSegment();
            return _groupSegment;
        }
    }
```

As I said, I know that if I just declare MultiSegmentBase as a public class instead of internal, I wouldn’t have this error, but since I’m making an API I don’t want to expose MultiSegmentBase and then further all the classes that derive from from MultiSegmentBase.

Basically, my quistion is why does MultiSegmentBase needs to be as accessible as E7XGroupBase and E7XSessionGroup, when I only use MultiSegmentBase in a protected property? And do any of you have a good workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you have a `public class` with a public property which is an `internal class`:

```
public abstract class E7XGroupBase
{
    protected abstract MultiSegmentBase GroupSegment { get; }
}
```

The `E7XGroupBase` can be extended by a class in a different assembly (since it's public) but that extending class couldn't resolve the `MultiSegmentBase` class because that is defined as internal.

This may help explain:

Assembly 1:

```
public abstract class E7XGroupBase
internal class MultiSegmentBase : SegmentBase
```

Assembly 2:

```
public class Something : E7XGroupBase
{
    // Can't resolve type MultiSegmentBase 
}
```

You either need to make `MultiSegmentBase` public, or create a public interface for it and use that in `E7XGroupBase`:

```
public interface IMultiSegmentBase { }

internal class MultiSegmentBase : IMultiSegmentBase {}

public abstract class E7XGroupBase
{
    protected abstract IMultiSegmentBase GroupSegment { get; }
}
```

Comment: But of course - "but that extending class couldn't resolve the MultiSegmentBase" Haven't thought of that. Thanks a lot @Trevor Pilley

Answer (score 2):

This is because MultiSegmentBase is internal which means it can only be accessed by classes in the same assembly.

Protected means that that it can be only accessed by derived classes. But derived classes does have to sit in the same assembly that's why compiler is giving you this error.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I'm not sure though that your proposal would solve the error, since the error is that the class that implements the 'GroupSegment' property is public, but the MultiSegmentBase type is internal. So any classes that inherit from my E7XGroupBase outside the assembly wouldn't know how to implement GroupSegment, since they wouldn't know the MultiSegmentBase type. Nopes this makes sense.

Comment: You're totally right. I will remove irrelevant part of my post. I should drink more coffee. Cheers!

Comment: No problem :-) But again, thanks for taking the time to try and help me. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`protected abstract MultiSegmentBase GroupSegment { get; }`

is a protected property meaning that it can be accessed within `E7XGroupBase` or any type that derives from `E7XGroupBase`, since `E7XGroupBase` is a public abstract class. ***However***, the type of the property `MultiSegmentBase` is internal, meaning that it can only be accessed within the assembly in which it is defined.

How to fix this depends; Should types in another assembly be able to inherit from `E7XGroupBase`? If so, you need to make `MultiSegmentBase` and `SegmentBase` more accessible so that they can also be accessed in another assembly.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. "Should types in another assembly be able to inherit from E7XGroupBase" - No - but types outside the assembly should be able to use/access classes that derive from E7XGroupBase. I would rather not make MultiSegmentBase more accessible. It would confuse the user of my API.

Comment: in which case, having a public interface as Trevor suggested above is a good approach.